# Ubuntu 17.10 hangs up on black screen while starting

Tags: 17.10

I upgraded ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10 but when i restarted ubuntu it hangs up on a black screen.Now,every time it's just hangs up on the black screen. Pleaze provide some solution i can't access my laptop.

Comment: Can you `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F2` to login via the console, and can you post what is output from `tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Stopping disk manager...        [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="828" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.